# How can I remove annoying messages about versioning from Xcode?

Tags: macos, xcode, swift

Practicing a bit with the Swift language, I am currently using Xcode v.9.2 in the playground mode. While coding, every time I just add a single statement, the following window appears:
[image]

Is it possible to make this window not appear so frequently? If yes, how? In the long run, its appearance is really annoying and the consequent workflow interruptions are incredibly disturbing.

Comment: Are you using the beta of Mojave or Xcode?

Comment: @fsb, I'm using Xcode v.9.2 on macOs Sierra v.10.12.

Comment: Generally, this message means that the file you are editing in Xcode has been edited in another instance (edited by another software or moved from initial emplacement). So Xcode doesn't really understand why the file changed and ask you if you want to keep the Xcode version or the other version edited by a third party tool. The best way to never get this message again is to edit your file into Xcode ;)

Comment: @StrawHara OP states they're doing development in Playground mode which is in the Xcode environment.  @rudicangiotti Are you loading data into the playground or using a source control system?  Try doing a `Product -> Clean` and then force quit Xcode.  See if that helps.  As you can tell, many things can cause this error to appear.

Comment: @fsb, unfortunately it seems I cannot click on that menu item. In particular, all the `Product` menu entries are not clickable.